# Youtube on Safari won't zoom enough

Tags: safari, youtube, zoom

I'm on youtube on Safari on my Mac. I'm on "View Actual Size", and the browser is taking up my entire screen, and yet, for some bizarre reason, the width of the content is exceeding the width of my screen, so that I constantly have to scroll back and forth to see all the content.

Safari allows me shrink the content through "Zoom out", and this reduces the problem somewhat. But after 3 clicks on "Zoom out", the feature becomes disabled, and I cannot Zoom out anymore, and the width of the content still exceeds the width of the screen?! Every other browser first of all doesn't have this problem to begin with, and secondly, let's me zoom out as much as I want!

And yet another problem: related videos shows only a thumbnail -- no text! Again, only on Safari?!

Going into theater mode solves the problem -- but I don't like theater mode -- I now have to scroll down every time I want to see related videos, a major inconvenience.

I've been using youtube for about a decade, and this is the first time I've ever had any such silly issues with it, all thanks to Safari. :(

Safari Version 8.0 (10600.1.25)
On a Mac OS X Yosemite Version 10.10 iMac 27-inch

Comment: Clarifications… what size is 'actual size'? What resolution is your screen? 2 click on Zoom out gives me a postage stamp in the middle of my screen, so I'm guessing you have a low-rez monitor setting, or you're watching a 2k or higher video.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that the main problem is that I forgot that I had installed a plugin that automatically zooms in!

Comment: There ya go then ;) Glad you got it. If I was sufficiently cynical, now would be the time for me to post an answer saying "Check your Safari plugins in case one of them auto-zooms" ;)